# The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent2,Column name = Course_CourseId ]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I always received this error as stated above.

---

I've recreated the Front Model and also the Front Controller yet I've received the same problem.

---

### Front Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Module1.Models
{
public class Front
{
    public int FrontId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int TotalHrs { get; set; }
    public int LectHrs { get; set; }
    public int TutHrs { get; set; }
    public int PracHrs { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Prerequisite { get; set; }

    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

### Front Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Module1.Models;

namespace Module1.Controllers
{
public class FrontController : Controller
{
    private SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Topic/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var fronts = db.Fronts.Include(t => t.Module);
        return View(fronts.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Topic/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        var mod = db.Modules.Include("Fronts").Single(t => t.ModuleId == id);
        return View(mod);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Topic/Create

    public ActionResult Create(int ID)
    {
        var modules = db.Modules.Where(m => m.ModuleId == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (modules != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Code = modules.Code;
            ViewBag.Description = modules.Description;
        }
        Front model = new Front();
        model.ModuleId = ID;
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Topic/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Front front)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Fronts.Add(front);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = front.ModuleId });
        }

        ViewBag.ModuleId = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code", front.ModuleId);
        return View(front);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Topic/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var modules = db.Modules.Where(m => m.ModuleId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (modules != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Code = modules.Code;
            ViewBag.Description = modules.Description;
        }
        Front front = db.Fronts.Find(id);
        ViewBag.ModuleId = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code", front.ModuleId);
        return View(front);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Topic/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Front front)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(front).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = front.ModuleId });
        }
        ViewBag.ModuleId = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code", front.ModuleId);
        return View(front);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Topic/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Front front = db.Fronts.Find(id);
        return View(front);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Topic/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Front front = db.Fronts.Find(id);
        db.Fronts.Remove(front);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = front.ModuleId });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    }
```

### }

The error above pops up when it is proceeding to my

#### Front Details

---

### Front Details View

```
@model Module1.Models.Front

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>Front</legend>

<div class="display-label">Module</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Module.Code)
</div>

<div class="display-label">ModuleName</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</div>

<div class="display-label">ModuleCode</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Code)
</div>

<div class="display-label">TotalHrs</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalHrs)
</div>

<div class="display-label">LectHrs</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LectHrs)
</div>

<div class="display-label">TutHrs</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TutHrs)
</div>

<div class="display-label">PracHrs</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PracHrs)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Year</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Year)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Prerequisite</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Prerequisite)
</div>
</fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.FrontId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add Record", "Create", new { id = Model.ModuleId})
    </p>

    <p>
       @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Index", "SchoolManager")
    </p>
```

---

MY ERROR

The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent2,Column name = Course_CourseId ]

Comment: I don't see `CourseId` anywhere in your code?

Comment: That is why I am lost right now too. @mattytommo

Comment: The previous front had it so i deleted and re-created but the same error occurred.

Comment: Did the same error occur because didn't recreate the database with the new fields? I don't understand how it would complain about `CourseId` given that there are no references to it in the code.

Comment: I dropped the table and recreated it but its still does not help? Do you need me to screenshot the Database? If it helps you? @mattytommo